# Unexpected behaviour of function table with "NaN" values

Tags: r, na

Recently, I've faced a behaviour in `table` function that was not what I was expected:

For example, let take the following vector:

```
ex_vec <- c("Non", "Non", "Nan", "Oui", "NaN", NA)
```

If I check for `NA` values in my vector, `"NaN"` is not considered one (as expected):

```
is.na(ex_vec)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But if I tried to get the different values frequencies:

```
table(ex_vec)
#ex_vec
#Nan Non Oui 
#  1   2   1
```

`"NaN"` does not appear in the table.

However, if I "ask" `table` to show the `NA` values, I get this:

```
table(ex_vec, useNA="ifany")
#ex_vec
# Nan  NaN  Non  Oui <NA> 
#   1    1    2    1    1
```

So, the character strings `"NaN"` is treated as a `NA` value inside `table` call, while being treated in the ouput as a not `NA` value.

I know (it would be better and) I could solve my problem by converting my vector to a `factor` but nonetheless, I'd really like to know what's going on here. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: this is just the basic usage.. like "why does `sum(c(1, NA))` return NA?" `table(..., exclude = if (useNA == "no") c(NA, NaN), useNA = c("no", "ifany", "always")` I don't understand the purpose of these answers

Comment: @rawr to explain the why a *string* is considered as a `NaN` value ? This is not the usage being asked, but the why. It is less obvious than your sum example which is covered by the doc. (I mean : `NaN != "NaN"`so why is `"NaN"` excluded as it's not part of the exclude vector)

Comment: @Tensibai again, the docs say `exclude: levels to remove for all factors` _levels_ are not `NA` nor are they `NaN`, they are _strings_.. aways _strings_ try `table(1, exclude = 1)`

Comment: @rawr I clearly understand this is obvious to you, according to this question score (and to my own head scratching to get the root cause), it is not that obvious for everyone... So I do think the answer would help others. (and `NA` is a valid level, even not being a string object, but I get your point `NaN`is not valid in a character vector)

Comment: Settle down, everyone! I think it's reasonable to find this behavior confusing. `exclude` can reasonably be read to refer to elements _of the supplied vector_ to exclude. Hence it might be surprising that if you tell it to exclude `NaN`, which is numeric, it would still exclude `"NaN"` which is character.

Comment: Thanks @Joran to express it far better than me ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `factor` matches up levels for a vector it converts its `exclude` list to the same type as the input vector:

```
exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
```

so if your exclude list has `NaN` and your vector is character, this happens:

```
as.vector(exclude, typeof(letters))
[1] NA    "NaN"
```

Oh dear. Now the real `"NaN"` strings will be excluded.

To fix, use `exclude=NA` in `table` (and `factor` if you are making factors that might hit this).

I do love this in the docs for `factor`:

```
 There are some anomalies associated with factors that have ‘NA’ as
 a level.  It is suggested to use them sparingly, e.g., only for
 tabulation purposes.
```

Reassuring...

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear answer (I love the quote from the factor doc too!)

Answer (score 5):

First idea coming to my mind was to have a look at `table` definition which start by:

```
> table
function (..., exclude = if (useNA == "no") c(NA, NaN), useNA = c("no", 
    "ifany", "always"), dnn = list.names(...), deparse.level = 1) 
{
```

Sounds logical, by default table exclude `NA` and `NaN`.

Digging within table code we see that if `x`is not a factor it coerce it to a factor (nothing new here, it's said in the doc).

```
    else {
        a <- factor(a, exclude = exclude)
```

I didn't find anything else which could have impacted the input to coerce `"NaN"` into `NA` values.

So looking into factor to get the why we find the root cause:

```
> factor
function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
    ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA) 
{
 [...] # Snipped for brievety
    exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
    x <- as.character(x)
    levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))] # defined in the snipped part above, is the sorted unique values of input vector, coerced to char.
    f <- match(x, levels)
 [...]
    f
}
```

Here we got it, the exclude parameter, even being `NA` values is coerced into a character vector.

So what happens is:

```
> ex_vec <- c("Non", "Non", "Nan", "Oui", "NaN", NA)
> excludes<-c(NA,NaN)
> as.vector(excludes,"character")
[1] NA    "NaN"
> match(ex_vec,as.vector(excludes,"character"))
[1] NA NA NA NA  2  1
```

We do match character "NaN" as the exclude vector as been coerced to character before comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai for the explanation! Why does "NaN" remains ordered in the `table` results as a regular value though and not at the end with `<NA>` ?

Comment: @CathG Because the levels are sorted at creation ;) See the comment in factor code on `levels` line, once not excluded they become normal entries

Comment: @CathG when table parameter is set to something else than 'no' they are not removed and treated as normal strings with no special meaning